Не работает YouTube через ShadowSocks с мобильной сети
У меня на сервере (22 убунту) установлен Outline, самый последний. Какая-то напасть некоторое время назад началась, перестал грузиться ютуб с мобильной сети, с вайфая всё прекрасно работает. В чём может быть проблема? Пишет ошибку, что не может проверить сертификат SSL, приложение не открывается по этой же причине, судя по всему. Пробовал прокидывать DNS гугловские на сервер в Германии, но безуспешно, никак не могу понять в чём дело.
